# Jquery DataTable - Change Server Side data format

Tags: jquery, datatables, coldfusion, datatables-1.10

I am using jQuery data table 1.10. While trying to POST the data to server I am getting data as array. Example below.

```
order[0][dir]
order[0][column]
```

**Is there anyway to change this array format to string as below,**

```
order[0][dir] => 'dir'
order[0][column] => 'column'
```

Code snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                 "ajax": {
                    "url": "../scripts/pagination_srvr_prcss.cfm",
                    "type": "POST"
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: You can either change the data from before sending from CF or can update in client side before feeding.
Alternatively, you can use the array of arrays format for datatables and it won't require any format change and you can pass `queryName.DATA`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data to populate from values in the `order[x]` arrays, you can use the `columns` key - e.g, assuming you want the table to show, for each row, [ dir | column ], I believe you can do:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    [...]
    ajax: {
        url: '../scripts/pagination_srvr_prcss.cfm',
        type: 'POST',
        columns: [
         { data: 'dir' },
         { data: 'column }
        ]
    }
});
```

If not, please clarify further, but the easiest way to do this would be to modify the data on the CF end before you send it back